# noip2 can't update my IP address correctly after computer reboot

Tags: debian, ip, init-script

I want to set up a server with using no-ip DDNS service. 
I follow [this guide](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/No_IP_Manual.html), but it can't update my IP address after reboot 
the following message is command `# noip2 -S`

```
  1 noip2 process active.

  Process 501, started as noip2, (version 2.1.9)
  Using configuration from /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
  Last IP Address set 0.0.0.0
  Account XXX@XXXXXX
  configured for:
          host  XXXXXX.noip.me
  Updating every 30 minutes via /dev/ppp0 with NAT enabled.
```

after I login and command `# service noip2 restart`

it can update my IP address. 
How can I correct it ?

My OS is debian 8

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error, IP 0.0.0.0 and working after manual service restart.

To fix this I simply put a delay for the script to run the client (and update the IP-address) with 'sleep 10' after 'start)' - line.

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/noip2.sh

# Supplied by no-ip.com
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Eivind L. Rygge <eivind@rygge.org>
# corrected 1-17-2004 by Alex Docauer <alex@docauer.net>

# . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions  # uncomment/modify for your killproc

DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/noip2
NAME=noip2

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting dynamic address update: "
    sleep 10
    start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Shutting down dynamic address update:"
    start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry 30 --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;

    restart)
    echo -n "Restarting dynamic address update: "
    start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo --retry 30 --exec $DAEMON
    start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON
    echo "noip2."
    ;;

    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: That worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I encountered the same issue (0.0.0.0 in Last IP).
The thing that worked for me was to just add 2 rules INPUT and OUTPUT for port 8245 TCP in my iptables.